# Proof kernel is cyclic and has order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Practicing for my exam tomorrow:

Let $n$ be a positive whole number. Let $\phi : (\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z})^* \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^*,$ $\phi(a$ mod $n^2)=a$ mod $n$

Proof the kernel of $\phi$ is cyclic and of order $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first we can just see what the kernel is: it is $\{kn + 1: 0 \leq k < n \} \subset (\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. We have $(kn +1)(ln + 1) = kln^2 + (k + l)n + 1 \equiv (k+l)n + 1$, so the kernel of $\phi$ is cyclic.